# Replace the current page with HTML from AJAX call

Tags: jquery

**Please vote to close this question. I am using a partial view now and things work perfectly!**

I make a successful post. I understand that result here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pagination a').live('click', function() {
        $.post(this.href, $('form').first().serialize(), function(result) {

        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

...corresponds to the response body. So can I, and I know this sounds stupid, replace the current page with this HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I am missing someting, but you should be able to place this in your callback:

$(window).html(result);

Comment: sorry does not work. submit() seems to be an alternative but form data is not send. How can I submit() plus form parameters? Thanks

Comment: The only problem I see with that is that you will have <body><html><body> etc, etc. maybe $(document) ? Sorry, I hope someone more experienced can chime in.

Comment: this seems to work. thanks. I will see if someone else answers before I accept ...

Comment: I have actually opted for a partial view now. This make it work perefecty! I am using $("#grid").replaceWith($("#grid", result));